# Ideals in Dedekind domain

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

If I is a non-zero ideal in a Dedekind domain such that $I^m$ and $I^n$ are principal, and are equal to $(a)$ and $(b)$ respectively. How to show that $I^{(m,n)}$ is principal.
Try: $(m,n) = rm +sn$ So, $I^{(m,n)} = (a)^r(b)^s$,  where $r$, $s$ can be positive and negative. Both positive case is ok. but how to handle other cases.

Comment: Are you familiar with the class group?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with class group. I have done only first 3 chapters of marcus` book

Comment: Do you know about fractional or invertible ideals? And what "other" cases do you mean?

Comment: @MathGems He seems to be saying that $m$ and $n$ are integers and he can deal with the case where both are positive. So presumably he's aware of fractional ideals.

Comment: @JSchlather: I guess $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers. It's $r$ and $s$ that can be negative and $r<0,s>0$ or $r>0,s<0$ are the 'other cases'.

Comment: @Michalis, Yes I think you're right. My mistake.

Comment: @qwert There is an exercise in Marcus Chapter 3 that asks you to prove that every fractional ideal is invertible in the sense that if $\mathfrak{a}$ is fractional then there exists $\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = \mathcal{O}_K$. Once you know this your question should be immediate.

Answer (score 3):

Denote by $e=(m,n)$. There exist $r, s>0$ such that $rm=sn+e$.

Write $I^m=(a)$ and $I^n=(b)$, then $(a^r)=(b^s)I^e\subseteq (b^s)$. This implies in particular that $a^r=b^sc$ for some $c$ in your domain. Simplifying by $b^s$ (this is always possible in an integral domain), we get $(c)=I^e$.

As said David in the comments, this holds in any integral domain.

Answer (score 2):

Even in the other cases the argument works, you just have fractional ideals instead. Viewing $I$ as an element $\overline{I}$ of the [ideal class group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) of $A$ your question can be stated as: Suppose $\overline{I}^m=\overline{I}^n=0$ in the ideal class group, then $\overline{I}^{(m,n)}=0$. This statement is true in any group.

Comment: The questioner says he doesn't know what the class group is. Conveniently, this question is actually true in any domain, so we don't need to use the fact that ideals in a Dedekind domain form a group.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I know. I posted my question before his comment. I guess I'll still leave it here, since this is probably the quickest way to do it if one knows about the ideal class group.

Comment: OK, makes sense.